# HTML e-mail works fine in browser and gmail app but not in native iphone e-mail client

Tags: python, email, gmail, html-email, gmail-api

I wrote a python script that sends an html email that includes texts and images. I can view e-mail perfectly in gmail through gmail app or dekstop browser but images got distorted when I open it in my native iphone e-mail client(not with gamil but with my hotmail account, if that matters).

**My first question**: Is there any way to fix this?

**If no, then my second question is**: I always see beautiful e-mail campaigns that works in every email clients. How do companies achieve that?

note/ My final code to send the e-mail:

```
message = MIMEText(text,'html')
message['to'] = all_list
message['from'] = ''
message['subject'] = ""
raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
raw = raw.decode()
message = {'raw': raw}
gmail_service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=message).execute()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, email HTML gets parsed differently in every mail client and the way to generate an email template that would look as expected on all of them is based on correct table usage. 
If you're interested in learning more about how to do it correctly, [read this article](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770).

If you're just looking for a way to make it work, you may assist one of those email template builders:

1. https://stripo.email/
2. https://beefree.io/

Number 1 did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to first question: Yes you can fix it but it is tedious and alot of work (or use simple email templates)

Second: Bigger companies use software like Mailchimp or Selligent. They make the mailings and compatible for other devices (emails are really anoying because every client interpret html differently)

Answer (score 0):

Base64 images do not work in Hotmail or Outlook.

The best way to display images in html emails is to host them on a web site and include a link to them in the email. This works on all modern email clients.

**example**:

```
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/170" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" border="0">
```

**More Information**:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2019/04/embedded-images-in-html-email/